# Melee System In Javascript Producing Unknown Errors?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, unityscript

```
#pragma strict

var Damage : int;
var Distance : float;

function update ()
{

  if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"));
  {
    var hit : RaycastHit;
    if (Physics.Raycast (transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), hit));
    {
      Distance=hit.distance;
      hit.transform.SendMessage("Apply Damage", Damage, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);


    }
  }
}
```

Above is the code for my melee system in my Unity3d Video Game, However I am getting the following errors:

> -> Assets/MeleeSystem.js(11,1): BCE0043: Unexpected token: var.
>
> -> Assets/MeleeSystem.js(11,4): UCE0001: ';' expected. Insert A Semicolon at the end.
>
> -> Assets/MeleeSystem.js(11,5): BCE0043: Unexpected token: hit.
>
> -> Assets/MeleeSystem.js(14,9): BCE0044: expecting :, found '='.

***Please explain all changes in detail.***

Comment: That looks *nothing* like Javascript

Comment: @ManofSnow it's not Java, it's the Unity3D scripting language that the company erroneously (fraudulently?) calls "JavaScript".

Comment: @Pointy I see, comment edited

Comment: @Pointy They don't call it JavaScript, they call it UnityScript. http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/UnityScript_versus_JavaScript

Comment: @Roberto oh well OK then :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the `;` at the end of both `if`-Lines

```
if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
{
```

Seems like the parser could not recover from that error and thus you get these errors.

Comment: Thank You So Much,

Sometimes the simplest things can fly right past your eye, can I give you rep i'm new to this and how?

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted, so others see the problem is resolved and your question is not listed as unanswered anymore.

Comment: @user3175902: Click on the "check mark" at the left of this answer, just under its score.